# Error with listview in dialog

Tags: java, android

I have been on this error now for a while. I am trying to open a list view in my dialog but its not opening for me this is my code.

[LOGCAST](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2526/37805964.jpg)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mybasicapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Slashscreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tutorialsone"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mybasicapp.TUTORIALSONE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Java code:

```
   public class menu extends Activity{


Button ImagebuttonOpenDialog;

 String KEY_TEXTPSS = "TEXTPSS";
 static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;

 ListView dialog_ListView;

 String[] listContent = {
   "January", "February", "March", "April",
   "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
   "October", "November", "December"};


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImagebuttonOpenDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
    ImagebuttonOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
           }});

            }

         @Override
         protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

          Dialog dialog = null;

          switch(id) {
             case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
              dialog = new Dialog(menu.this);
              dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
              dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

              dialog.setCancelable(true);
              dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

              dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(menu.this,
               "OnCancelListener",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

              dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(menu.this,
               "OnDismissListener",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

              //Prepare ListView in dialog
              dialog_ListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
               = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
              dialog_ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
              dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(menu.this,
               parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " clicked",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
            }});

                 break;
             }

          return dialog;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle bundle) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog, bundle);

          switch(id) {
             case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
              //
                 break;
             }

         }

        }
```

activity_main xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/carbon" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottombar" >
</FrameLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbtn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgbtn1"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgbtn1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgbtn1"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgbtn2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/kj" />
```

custom.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/customdialog"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
android:minWidth="300dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dialoglist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/kj" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ALSO
    I looked over the java code again and found that my code had (button) where in my XML had image button i have change my java code so you can see where i am at the moment..still no luck.I don't know how to copy log cast

Comment: What is at line 39 of `menu`?

Comment: Looks like it's not finding your button in findViewById.  Show us your layout.  That image with your logcat is quite poor.  A print out of the entire exception would be helpful.

Comment: Please copy and paste the stacktrace here.

Comment: Please don't change your OP as it will be confusing and useless for future visitors. Now, you said you changed it but it still shows you defining it as `Button` instead of `ImageButton`. If you have changed that then indicate which is line 39 because it can't be a `NPE` on that `Button`. You should be able to directly copy/paste the errors in logcat. Or you can highlight them and click the save icon in the logcat view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my count, `buttonOpenDialog` is `null` so you are getting `NPE` when you try to add a `listener` to it. Check your `activity_main` that you have a `Button` with an id of `im1`. You probably misspelled the id or that one simply doesn't exist in your `layout`. If you don't see a problem with that then post the `activity_main.xml`.

Also, this isn't your problem but you should consider using Java standard naming conventions. Class names should start with a capital letter. So you would have `Main` instead of `main` as your class name.

When you post a question please post the logcat in your question as it always makes it easier for members to read then needing to follow a link that sometimes isn't of the best quality.

Comment: Thank you you was right about the id's i missed it.And i will learn to use capitals. I feel like its a waste of a question BUT then i think people can use this code. Just need to learn how to call my data from sqlidatabse to list view